# Jasper Reports Calculating Count by Date part

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I have a report that lists events by the date on which they occurred.  As part of the report, I would to plot a chart of the number of events against the month and year.  To do this (I think) I need a Variable that counts events on the day-year part of the date.  I am not sure if this is possible without going to a sub report and using a Group By clause in the SQL (which I would prefer not to do if possible)?

The start of a solution may be to create a variable to select the Month and year and then use this as a key for a HashMap in another variable.

```
<variable name="DISCHARGE_MONTH_YEAR" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[new String ((new SimpleDateFormat("MM.yyyy").format($F{HosDateDis})))]]></variableExpression>
</variable>

<variable name="DEATHS_MONTH_YEAR" class="java.util.HashMap">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{DEATHS_MONTH_YEAR}.put($V{DISCHARGE_MONTH_YEAR},
$V{DEATHS_MONTH_YEAR}.get($V{DISCHARGE_MONTH_YEAR}) + 1)]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Comment: add a map variable, in the details band increment the matching entry in summary you can plot your chart.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I am not quite sure what you mean?  Are you suggesting that I create a HashMap say where the key is MMYYYY and the Value is incremented by the details band and then I would use the HashMap variable to chart?  Is this vaguely correct? Would it be a hassle to do a simple example?

Comment: Yes, like this. I can't make an example cause I don't have a JR nearby (or else I already would have and posted it as answer). When you are done & it works, please do post the example as answer.

Comment: I have added part of a possible solution.  I am not sure if this is correct, but I am trying to work out how to use a HashMap in a chart.